# Can't use the --globally in my npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I wanted to install a package with npm but it's impossible to use the -g in every command

- `npm install -g expo-cli`
- `npm list -g`
- ...

I obtain the same error every time :
[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLGw3.png)

" ELOOP : Too many symbolic links encountered stat ' \\srv_tse\profils_TS$\ '

---

Here is the log created of the error : [Log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/synwI.png)

---

I've tried to clear my cache via the command : `npm cache clear --force` but it didn't work.

---

- Node : v14.15.1
- NPM : 6.14.8

Can someone help with my problem ?
Thanks !

Comment: have you tryed using cmd as Admin ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes I tried, the error remains the same even with administrator privilege.

Comment: try to clean cache, update to latest, you could have some corrup files

Comment: By clearing my cache, you mean those command : 
> npm cache clean, npm cache clear ?

And I installed Node yesterday, I don't think there is a new update today.

My Node version is : 14.15.1
And my npm version is : 6.14.8

Comment: Cleaning the cache works for me when it happens

Comment: yes @QuentinBlanche I am talking about npm cach clear..., you can also go to appdata and delelete the npm folder and install it again

Comment: When I try to run the command : npm cache clear I have this message that appear : If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
Should I give it a shot ?

Comment: Even with my cache clear, the error remain. I don't really know what to do more. It's a fresh install after all.